# Object key name created from an array value javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I'm trying to make an object whose keys come from an array. But if I use the object name as `array[i]`, I get the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [`

```
itemKeys: {
       for (var i = 0; i < category_keys.Length; i++) {
            category_keys[i]: "font-size: 15px; color: black;",
           }
        }
```

I'm still learning JavaScript and can't find a way to get around this one.

**EDIT**

Looking at some comments and answers maybe it isn't an object. It is pre made coding originally as.

```
a.extend(a.Editor.DEFAULTS, {
        itemKeys: {
            "dropdown name 1": "font-size: 15px; color: black;",
            "dropdown name 2": "font-size: 15px; color: black;",
        }})
```

I want to change the dropdown names that are displayed as different text chosen from looping through an array.

Sorry for any confusion

**EDIT 2**

itemKeys I could only guess is an object (`typeof` gives undefined). This is from a plugin. I cant change the main object this is `.extend` ing from because I don't want to change the core coding of the plugin and have things go wrong. Thats why i just wanted to change and loop through the keys values ("dropdown name 1") or maybe I should say the first of the 2 values if that what it is.

I should also note even if for the original coding I change just `itemKeys: {` to `itemKeys = {` it breaks and gives the error 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token =' same goes for `"dropdown name 1":` so sadly all the answers that use the '=' sign don't work at all.

I'm not a js whiz so I only assumed it was a standard object, clearly it isn't and I really don't know what type itemKey is. It most likely is some more advanced thing that a js noob like me doesn't even know exists.

My guess is that if you know what itemKey is by the syntax then you might know how to loop through its values or keys and values.

Comment: Your syntax is completely invalid. You can't run loops in an [object initializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer). Or is it a label and a block? No idea what you are attempting to achieve.

Comment: do you mean for that block to be a function?

Answer (score 1):

That would be invalid syntax for object literal.

You may try like:

```
var a = {};
var category_keys = ['font','color'];

for (var i = 0; i < category_keys.Length; i++) {
   a[category_keys[i]] =  "font-size: 15px; color: black;";
}
```

Reference: [Object Initializer](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_11.1.5)

Comment: I have updated my question. It might be a bit more clear now. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you mean something like this. It takes two arrays. one of keys and the other of values to generate an object. Much like the php array_combine function

```js
function arrayCombine( keys, values ){
  if( keys.length !== values.length ){
    throw new Error('keys and values must have the same length');
  }
  // object to return
  var obj = {};
  // loop through the keys and value.
  for( var ii = 0, ll = keys.length; ii < ll; ii++ ){
    obj[ keys[ii] ] = values[ ii ];
  }
  return obj;
}
  
var myObj = arrayCombine( ['my-key'], ['font-size: 15px; color: black;'] ),
    // with multiple keys and values
    otherObj = arrayCombine(['foo', 'bar'], ['foo value', 'bar value']);
  
console.log( myObj );
console.log( otherObj );
```

```html
<script src="http://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/WrQapG.js"></script>
```

Here is a different version that uses functional js principals to save some of the repetition.

```js
// this is a functional style function that will curry the styles
// and allow you to pass in multiple keys that have those same styles
function fontStyle( styles, keys ){
  return keys
    ? _fontStyle(keys)
    : _fontStyle;
  // helper function that does the work
  function _fontStyle( keys ){
    return keys.reduce(function( obj, key ){
      // styles is available from the parent functions scope
      obj[ key ] = styles;
      return obj;
    }, {} );
  }
}

var yourObject = { defaults: {} };

// create your specific font style functions these can be called like `pStyle('key')`
var pStyle  = fontStyle('font-size:1em;color:#111'),
    h1Style = fontStyle('font-size:2em;line-height:3em');

console.log( 'this is the actual function', pStyle );

$.extend(yourObject.defaults,
   // run the font style functions passing in the keys      
   pStyle(['content', 'paragraph']),
   pStyle(['text']),
   h1Style(['heading', 'title']),
   // you can even call the functions without initializing them
   fontStyle('font-size:1em;color:red')(['link']),
   fontStyle('font-size:3em;color:#3cf', ['big', 'huge'])
);

console.log( yourObject );
```

```html
<script src="http://codepen.io/synthet1c/pen/WrQapG.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Great answer and the output in the snippet looks right but im struggling to see how I implement that from the original (the edit i added). Parts I dont get is would that all go inside `a.extend(a.Editor.DEFAULTS, {`? and `var obj = {};` is for `itemKeys: {} `? Sorry for making you dumb it down more. i code in ruby and just started on js recently. This isn't my coding originally and im not even sure if itemKeys is an object, just guessing from looking at it because i cant think of anything else it might be.

Comment: @user3234020 what does the `category_keys` array look like.

Comment: category_keys=["key1","key2","key3"];

Comment: I think you are over complicating the problem. In my opinion you are always better off being more explicit. what is wrong with using: `$.extend(yourObject, {key1: 'font-size:12px;color:#fff', key2: 'font-size:12px;color:#fff', key3: 'font-size:12px;color:#fff' }` if you write a function it will take time to figure out what the function to fill the object keys does when debugging. but you know instantly what the above code does without thinking and it only costs a few more characters. Whoever deals with your code will thank you later. but @mithunsatheesh has the correct answer for the question.

Comment: The reason for the complication is because i'm adding some customisation to a plugin. I don't want to go changing the core coding setup of the plugin for something so little so i figured passing arrays to the keys would be the fix. Ill give @mithunsatheesh answer a shot

Comment: I'll have to give your second answer a crack tomorrow. Thanks for the help. I have also updated my question again to give more insight on the problem which might change your answer.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have category_keys defined, such as:

```
var category_keys=["key1","key2","key3"];
```

define itemKeys:

```
var itemKeys={};
```

run this loop, change "value" to whatever you want:

```
for (var i=0;i<category_keys.length; i++)
  itemKeys[category_keys[i]]={value:"font-size: 15px; color: black;"};
```

to access value:

```
var anyvar=itemKeys["key1"].value;
```

*use "length", not "Length"

Comment: well?  which answer did you use?

Answer (score 0):

This should work if you, from what I understand, are trying to rename the keys while keeping the values the same.  The reduce function iterates each element of the "keys" array, using the return-value of the callback as the value passed in as "prev" for the each successive call (starting with {}).

```
var keys=["key1","key2","key3"] 

var itemKeyVals = {
    "dropdown name 1": "font-size: 15px; color: black;",
    "dropdown name 2": "font-size: 15px; color: black;"
}
// Get array of the keys we would like to replace
var itemKeys = Object.keys(itemKeyVals);

var newObj = keys.reduce( function(prev, curr, index, arr){ 
    // if no more keys to replace return new generated dict
    if (!itemKeys[index]) return prev;
    // assign to key Val in new dict the value of the old dict
    prev[curr] = itemKeyVals[itemKeys[index]];
    return prev;
}, {});
```